# How to change a HTML document dynamically with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I've managed to separate my PHP and HTML code completely by using something like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents("HTML_doc_with_no_php_in_it.html");
eval("print \"" . addcslashes(preg_replace("/( ---(.+?)---)/", "\\2", $html), '"') . "\";");
```

What this code does is that it replaces the part in the HTML document that says `---$var---` with the value of the variable `$var` in my PHP-document. So by doing this I'm allowed to generate a HTML-document with my changed value of the variable, without there being any PHP in the HTML-document.

What I want to do now is to change this document from being able to take a static amount of PHP code to being able to take a dynamic amount of PHP code. As of now I can only change that particular field in my HTML-code that's marked with "---" in the beginning and the end and has the same name as the variable in my PHP document. But what if I don't know how much PHP I want to generate to HTML in my HTML document and I want it to be able to generate an arbitrary amount of HTML code? Is this possible?

Comment: You realize you have an `eval` in your code right? right?

Comment: eval() is a high impact security risk. Don't use it in a production enviornment.

Comment: From the php manual "Caution
The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.", always check the docs =] http://php.net/eval

Comment: Eval is evil. I suggest you use twig for templating http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: @yamikoWebs wow that escalated quickly

Comment: Well this is an university assignment, and the first assignment was to do "static code separation" by using "eval()", so I used it. I've read some about it being a high security risk etc, but since my course coordinator will be the only one seeing this documents except me I guess it's okay though? Feel free to tell me that I'm wrong, but I still need to get a pass on this assignment and I guess that I should follow the instructions to accomplish that.

Did someone hint at eval() being able to do dynamic code separation as well?